# Multiple-entry Type D visa - Re-entering in a different country

Tags: visas, schengen, long-stay-visas

I have a Multiple-entry Type D visa for a country in the Schengen area. I am aware that I have 90 days within an 180-day period to travel around the Schengen area. I plan to visit Italy during this time, but decided to join a spring break trip to Romania and Bulgaria that has me return to Italy for a week before returning to the country associated with my visa. This trip takes place one week before Romania and Bulgaria join the Air Schengen program.

Is it okay to re-enter the Schengen Area in a different country than the one that issued my visa and then stay in that other country a week before returning to my visa country? Or does the multiple-entry type D visa always require you re-enter the Schengen Area in the country that issued it?

Comment: For 100% clarity, have you already used your D visa to enter the issuing country?

Comment: Yes, I already entered the issuing country.

Comment: There is no requirement to enter the Schengen area through any particular country, not even the first time you use the visa.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it okay to re-enter the Schengen Area in a different country than the one that issued my visa and then stay at that other country a week before returning to my visa country?

Yes, a national (Type D) visa, when used outside of the issuing country, works exactly the same way as a Schengen (Type C) visa where you can enter or leave through any Schengen country.